# Linear Differential Equation achieving the answer.

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

The question states $t(\dfrac{dy}{dt}) - 3y = t^4$

As a first step I am told to divide through by $t^4$ - can anyone explain the purpose of this?

Following this I get $t^{-3} (\dfrac{dy}{dt}) - 3yt^{-4} = 1$

Then it says you can write this as $\dfrac{d}{dt}(t^{-3} y)=1$

Why can you then convert it to this? Can anyone explain with more steps this happening?

And then resulting from this how is the answer $y(t)=t^3(t+c)$ achieved?

Comment: I think my answer [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/753801/55235) answers your questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At first one we divide by $t$ and we find
$$y'=\frac3t y+t^3$$
the solutions of the homogeneous equation
$$y'=\frac3t y$$
are
$$y_h(t)=\lambda\exp\left(\int\frac3tdt\right)=\lambda t^3$$
and by the constant variation method a particular solution has the form
$$y_p(t)=\lambda(t)t^3$$
where
$$\lambda'(t)t^3=t^3\Rightarrow \lambda(t)=t$$
hence the solution of the given differential equation are
$$y(t)=\lambda t^3+t^4,\qquad \lambda\in\Bbb R$$

Answer (score 0):

Lets take a look at this line from your post:
$$t^{-3}\frac{dy}{dt}-3t^{-4}y = 1$$
If we say $u=t^{-3}$ and $v=y$ then we get,
$$u\cdot v' + u'\cdot v = 1$$
Which looks like our product rule for derivatives so we can rewrite this as $\frac{d}{dt}\left(u\cdot v\right)$.  Substituting back in we are left with,
$$\frac{d}{dt}\left( t^{-3}y \right) = 1$$
To find the solution just integrate both sides,
$$\int \frac{d}{dt}\left( t^{-3}y \right)dt = \int 1 dt$$
$$t^{-3}y = t + c$$
$$y = t^3(t+c)$$
Hope this helps.