# solve differential equation $y' + (\cos x)y = 4 \cos x$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$$y' + (\cos x)y = 4 \cos x$$

This can be done using the differential factor. I would say that the differential factor should be $e^{D\cos x} = e^{-\sin x}$. However I know it should be $e^{\sin x}$ since the answer is $$ y = 4+Ce^{-\sin x}$$

Can someone explain this to me?

If I could get a nice way to solve

$$ \int 4 \cos x e^{sinx} dx  $$

It would also be nice, I think there's a trick you can use instead of subsitute $tan \frac{x}{2} = t$

Comment: See the first part of this [answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/753801/55235).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT:

[Integrating Factor](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/IntegratingFactor.html)

$$e^{\int (\cos x)\ dx}=e^{\sin x}$$

Answer (score 3):

We have
\begin{align}
ye^{\sin{x}}
&=\int 4\cos{x}e^{\sin{x}}dx\\
&=4\int e^{\sin{x}}\operatorname{d}(\sin{x})\\
&=4e^{\sin{x}}+C
\end{align}
Hence
$$y=4+Ce^{-\sin{x}}$$

Answer (score 3):

- Notice that $y=4$ is a remarquable particular solution for the ODE.
- The homogeneous ODE
  $$y'+(\cos x) y=0\iff y=C\exp\left(-\int\cos xdx\right)=C\exp(-\sin x)$$
  so the general solution is the sum of the particular solution with a solution of the homogeneous ODE.

Comment: Is `remarquable` the same as`remarkable`? French version I think. :+)

Answer (score 2):

$$y' = (4-y)\cos x \stackrel{*}{\Rightarrow} \frac{dy}{4-y} = \cos x\ dx\Rightarrow \int \frac{dy}{y-4} = -\int\cos x\ dx \Rightarrow \\\ln y-4 = -\sin x + C \Rightarrow  y - 4 = Ke^{-\sin{x}} \Rightarrow y = Ke^{-\sin x}+4$$
With $K > 0$

$*$ Unless $y = 4$ wich is also a solution (that can be achieved considering $K \geq 0$)