# Find solution of differential equation $y'(t)=-2y(t)+1$

Tags: calculus, analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, exponential-function

Could you help me explain how to find the solution of the differential equation
$$
y'(t)=-2y(t)+1, 
$$
with 
$$y(0)=1.$$
I know that the solution is 
$$y(t)=\frac12 (1+e^{-2t}).$$

How about the IVP
$$y'(t)=1,\quad y(0)=1?$$

Comment: how is it discrete-mathematics?

Comment: See [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/753797/solving-a-differential-equation/753801#753801) answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This initial value problem has exactly one solution: If $y=y(t)$ is the solution, then
$$
\mathrm{e}^{2t}y'(t)=-2\mathrm{e}^{2t}y(t)+\mathrm{e}^{2t},
$$
or
$$
\big(\mathrm{e}^{2t}y(t)\big)'=\mathrm{e}^{2t}y'(t)+2\mathrm{e}^{2t}y(t)=\mathrm{e}^{2t}
=\left(\frac{1}{2}\mathrm{e}^{2t}\right)',
$$
or equivalently
$$
\mathrm{e}^{2t}y(t)=\frac{1}{2}\mathrm{e}^{2t}+c,
$$
where $c$ is some constant, and due to the fact that $y(0)=1$, the value of $c$ has to be $c=1/2$. Thus
$$
y(t)=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}\mathrm{e}^{-2t}.
$$

Note. The procedure followed above establishes uniqueness as well, for if $z=z(t)$ were another solution, then following for $z$ the same procedure we would reach to the same answer.

Edit. For the IVP
$$
y'=1,\quad y(0)=1,
$$
the unique solution is $y(t)=t+1$.

Comment: How about the other differential equation given by $$y(t)'=1 $$ and $$y(0)=1$$

Comment: See the edit in my answer.

Comment: Thank you. I cannot up vote your question because I don't have enough point. Sorry for that. BTW, what is IVP?

Comment: It's OK! - Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

So we have $$\frac{dy}{dt} = -2y + 1 \implies \frac{1}{-2y+1}dy = dt \implies \int \frac{1}{-2y+1}dy = \int dt$$ can you carry on from here? (Hint: natural logs. Also, remember the constant of integration!)

Answer (score 1):

**Homogenous solution**
$y'(t)=-2y(t)\iff \frac{y'(t)}{y(t)}=-2\iff\frac{dy}{y}=-2dt\iff \ln(y(t))=-2t+C\iff y(t)=De^{-2t}$

**Particular solution**

It's of the form $w(t)=c$. You remplace in the equation and you get
$-2c+1=0\iff c=\frac{1}{2}$

Finally, the solution is given by $$y(t)=De^{-2t}+\frac{1}{2}$$
And with the condition $y(0)=1$, we get
$$D+\frac{1}{2}=1\iff D=\frac{1}{2}$$
and so the solution is $$y(t)=\frac{1}{2}(1+e^{-2t})$$

Comment: How about the second question $$y(t)'=1$$

Comment: it's not necessary and also wrong because $y'(t)\neq 1$ for all $t\neq 0$

Comment: Sorry. The second question of my question that given the other formula where $$y(t)'=1 $$ and $$y(0)=1$$