# Explain how to get the right solution of y $dy/dx=y$

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, logarithms

When solving the following equation to find y as a function of x:

\begin{equation}
dy/dx=y
\end{equation}

First I divide both sides by $y$ and multiply both sides by $dx$:

$dy/y=dx$

Then I integrate both sides:

$\ln(y)+C1=x+C2$

Then:

$y=e^{x+C2-C1}=e^{x+C}$

I now know my result is problematic becomes $y=-e^x$ also satisfies $dy/dx=y$ but it is included in my solution: $y=e^{x+C}$. So can you help me find what is wrong with my analysis process and provide the right analysis process.

Thanks.

**Update:
I said $y=-e^x$ is not included in $y=e^{x+C}$ because $e^C>0$.**

Comment: $e^{x+C}=Ae^x$ as is the general solution.

Comment: I do not understand your problem. $y = \exp(x+C)$ is the general solution. For $C = i\,\pi$ this becomes $y = - \exp(x)$.

Comment: This procedure yields the ${\it form}$ of the answer.  Constants are, as always, free to vary.

Comment: See [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/753797/solving-a-differential-equation/753801#753801) answer.

Comment: @MartinR What I am confused is that normally $e^C>0$. I did not expect $C$ to be a complex number. Is there an alternative derivation process that assume all numbers are real and can still produce $y=Ce^x$ where C can be positive or negative?

Answer (score 1):

It should be noted that $$\int \frac{dy}{y} =\ln|y| + C$$ That absolute value is important.

This means that $|y| = De^x$ for some positive constant $D$.

The really odd trick is that $D=0$ works, as well...

Answer (score -2):

$$\frac{dy}{dx} = y \iff$$
$$\frac{1}{y} dy = dx \iff$$
$$ \int \frac{1}{y} dy = \int dx \iff $$
$$ \ln(y) + C_1 = x+C_2 \iff$$
$$ \ln(y)  = x+C \iff$$
$$e^{\ln(y)}  = e^{x+C} \iff$$
$$e^{\ln(y)}  = e^{x}e^{C} \iff$$

$$y = D e^x$$

where $D$ may be  chosen to satisfy the initial conditions:

For example, if $y(0) = \pi$, then $y(0) = De^0 = \pi \implies D=\pi$

Comment: Did you read the question? He is confused about why $y=-e^x$ is also a solution. Traditionally, $D=e^C>0$...