# Find solution of differential equation $y ′ (t)=−y(t)-\frac1{2}(1+e^{-2t})+1$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Could you help me to explain how to find the solution of this equation 
$$y ′ (t)=−y(t)-\frac1{2}*(1+e^{-2t})+1$$ 
Given $y(0)=0$
Thank all
This is my answer
$$y ′ (t)=−y(t)-\frac1{2}e^{-2t}+\frac1{2}$$ 
$$e^{2t}y ′ (t)=e^{2t}(−y(t)-\frac1{2}e^{-2t}+\frac1{2})$$
where
$$(e^{2t}y(t))′=e^{2t}y(t)′+2(e^{2t}y(t))=e^{2t}(y(t)-\frac1{2}e^{-2t}+\frac1{2})$$

Comment: Integrating factor method http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrating_factor

Comment: Yes. I try. I will upload my answer now

Comment: @nbubis: I updated my answer. But I did not found the solution

Comment: See [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/753797/solving-a-differential-equation/753801#753801) answer.

Comment: Note the reference is exactly what you need to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiply the equation by $e^t$, then
$$
e^t(y'+y)=\frac{e^t}{2}-\frac{e^{-t}}{2}
$$
or
$$
\big(e^t y\big)'=\frac{1}{2}\big(e^t+e^{-t}\big)'
$$
or
$$
e^t y=\frac{1}{2}\big(e^t+e^{-t}\big)+c,
$$
for some $c$ constant, or
$$
y=\frac{1}{2}\big(1+e^{-2t}\big)+c\,e^{-t}.
$$

Answer (score 1):

Reordering,
$$y'(t)+y(t)=\frac{1}{2}e^{-2t}+\frac{1}{2}$$

This DE is of the form 
$$y'(t)+P(t)y(t)=Q(t)$$
with $P(t)=1$ and $Q(t)=\frac{1}{2}e^{-2t}+\frac{1}{2}$.

Then, use the integrating factor 
$$M(t)=e^{\int_{t_0}^tP(x)\,dx}=e^{\int_{t_0}^t1\,dx}=e^{t-t_0}=e^{t-0}=e^t$$

So, in our DE,
$$\begin{array}{rcl}
M(t)y'(t)+M(t)y(t)&=&M(t)Q(t)\\
e^ty'(t)+e^ty(t)&=&e^t\bigg(\frac{1}{2}e^{-2t}+\frac{1}{2}\bigg)\\
\bigg(e^ty(t)\bigg)'&=&\frac{1}{2}\big(e^{t}+e^{-t}\big)\\
e^ty(t)&=&\frac{1}{2}\int_{t_0}^t\big(e^{t}+e^{-t}\big)\,dt\\
e^ty(t)&=&\frac{1}{2} \big(e^t-e^{-t}\big)\bigg|_{0}^{t}\\
y(t)&=&\frac{1}{2e^t} \big(e^{t-0}-e^{-(t-0)}\big)\\
y(t)&=&\frac{1}{2e^t} \big(e^{t}-e^{-t}\big)\\
\end{array}$$

---

Why use the integrating factor? Note that $M'(t)=P(t)M(t)$, so multiplying the integrating factor in the DE gives:
$$M(t)y'(t)+M(t)y(t)=M(t)Q(t)\Rightarrow \bigg(M(t)y(t)\bigg)'=M(t)Q(t)$$
So the solution is:
$$y(t)=\frac{1}{M(t)}\int_{t_0}^tM(x)Q(x)\,dx=\frac{1}{e^{\int_{t_0}^tP(x)\,dx}}\int_{t_0}^te^{\int_{t_0}^xP(s)\,ds}Q(x)\,dx$$

Comment: I think you missing C const in the solution. But your explain is perfect and the question is -1/2

Comment: Note that I use the initial condition, using $t_0=0$ when integrating. If you prefer, I can edit the answer so you take the initial condition after the calculation of the general solution...

Comment: Also, the $-1/2$ is multiplying a $1$, and you sum a $1$ afterwards.. do the math!

Answer (score 0):

one solution of the equation $y'(t)+y(t)=0$ is $y=C_1e^{-t}$

Comment: Which steps did you go through to arrive at this answer?

Comment: this is the theory about the solutions of linear differential equations

Answer (score 0):

Hints; Solve $$y'+y=\frac12 \left (1-e^{-2t} \right ) \stackrel{\cdot e^{\int 1 \mathrm{d}t}}{\iff} e^t y'+e^t y= e^t \frac12 \left (1-e^{-2t} \right )$$

Do you recognise the LHS as something familiar?

Answer (score 0):

Work it out assuming y = u*v, and y' = u'*v + u*v'.

Rearrange to y' + y = 1/2 - e<sup>-2t</sup>/2

Solve homogeneous equation

u' + u = 0

So u = C * e<sup>-t</sup>.

Now substitute for y in full equation

u'*v + u*v' + uv = 1/2 - e<sup>-2t</sup>/2

v*(u' + u) + u*v' = 1/2 - e<sup>-2t</sup>/2

0  + u*v' = 1/2 - e<sup>-2t</sup>/2

v' = e<sup>t</sup>/2 - e<sup>-t</sup>/2

Integrate

v = e<sup>t</sup>/2 + e<sup>-t</sup>/2

y = A*uv + B*u

= A*(1/2 + e<sup>-2t</sup>/2) + B*e<sup>-t</sup>

Checking y' + y  = -1/2(1 + e<sup>-2t</sup>/2 + 1 , find A = 1, and B is arbitrary.

y = (1/2 + e<sup>-2t</sup>/2) + B*e<sup>-t</sup>