# On solution to simple ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Consider the ODE $$\frac{dx}{dt} = ax + b$$ where $a$ and $b$ are two parameters.  The way to solve this is to divide both sides by $ax+b$ and integrate:

$$\int \frac{\dot x}{ax+b}dt = t+C \\ \frac{\log|ax+b|}{a} = t+C \\ x(t) = Ke^{at}-\frac ba$$

Easy enough.  But I'm not sure why we're not excluding some possible solutions in the first step of this approach.  Doesn't dividing by $ax+b$ immediately rule out any solution where $x(t)=-\frac ba$ anywhere in the interval over which the function is defined?  That seems like we might be losing a lot of potential solutions.  So why is the above solution the *general solution*?

Comment: The constant solution $x(t)=-b/a$ is an equilibrium solution, so it would be handled separately.

Comment: What about any function $x(t)$ to could potentially equal $-b/a$ at some finite number of points?  Or even infinitely many points that just isn't all of them in the interval?

Comment: "The way to solve this is" **not** to use separation of variables unnecessarily, but instead proceed in [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/753797/solving-a-differential-equation/753801#753801) fashion. But if you really want to use separation of variables, you can justify that those are the only solutions by using the [Picard–Lindelöf theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picard%E2%80%93Lindel%C3%B6f_theorem).

Comment: I see.  So this is only the way my book solves it -- not the most rigorous way.  Thanks @GitGud!

Comment: @user333824 You're welcome. You might also be interested in [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1137673/how-do-we-know-that-we-found-all-solutions-of-a-differential-equation?lq=1) question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right, and this is a good issue to point out. In this case, it's straightforward to show uniqueness, though: Suppose that $x(t)$ is a solution and notice that if $y(t) = e^{-at} x(t)$, we have

\begin{align*}
y'(t) &= -ae^{-at} x(t) + e^{-at} x'(t) \\
&= -ae^{-at} x(t) + e^{-at} \big(ax(t) + b\big) \\
&= be^{-at}
\end{align*}

Now integrating shows what $y$ must be, and hence $x$. No division by zero at all.

---

Sometimes, one can solve an equation in a somewhat *ad hoc* manner, as this separation of variables does, and then simply check that the solution is valid by substitution and unique by an easy argument like this one.