# Prove that if $f$ is holomorphic so that $f'(z)=\alpha f(z)$ then $f(z)=ce^{\alpha z}$

Tags: complex-analysis

Prove that if $f$ is holomorphic so that $f'(z)=\alpha f(z)$, $\alpha$ being a constant, for every $z \neq 0$ then $f(z)=ce^{\alpha z}$, $c \in \mathbb C$.

So what I tried doing is defining $g(z)=f(z)-ce^{\alpha z}$, and proving $g(z)$ is constant using Cauchy-Riemann. Obviously that didn't work out very well..

Any other **hints** will be great!

Comment: See [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/753797/solving-a-differential-equation/753801#753801).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the holomorphic function

$g(z) = e^{-\alpha z} f(z); \tag{1}$

we have

$g'(z) = -\alpha e^{-\alpha z} f(z) + e^{-\alpha z} f'(z)$
$= -\alpha e^{-\alpha z} f(z) + e^{-\alpha z} \alpha f(z) = 0; \tag{2}$

thus

$g(z) = c, \;\; \text{a constant}; \tag{3}$

and thus from (1),

$f(z) = ce^{\alpha z}.  \tag{4}$

***QED!!!***

***Note Added Saturday 25 April 2015 2:01 PM PST:***  We can, and perhaps should, say a little more.  If we know the value $f(z_0)$ of $f(z)$ at some point $z_0$, then from (4) we have

$f(z_0) = ce^{\alpha z_0},  \tag{5}$

whence

$c = f(z_0) e^{-\alpha z_0},  \tag{6}$

so we may in fact write (4) as

$f(z) = f(z_0) e^{-\alpha z_0} e^{\alpha z} = f(z_0) e^{\alpha(z - z_0)}. \tag{7}$

Writing $f(z)$ in the form (7) is a help to presenting $f(z)$ in the event that the domain $\Omega$ of $f(z)$ is allowed to have more than one topological component, i.e., in the event that it is not necessarily a connected subset of the complex plane.  For then we may only affirm from $g'(z) = 0$ that $g(z)$ is constant on each connected component of $\Omega$.  If we write

$\Omega = \bigcup_{i \in I} \Omega_i, \tag{8}$

where each $\Omega_i$ is a non-empty, connected open subset of $\Bbb C$ with $\Omega_i \cap \Omega_j = \emptyset$, for $i \ne j$, that is, $\Omega$ is topologically decomposed into the $\Omega_i$, then for each $i \in I$ we may choose $c_i \in \Bbb C$ and have

$g(z) = c_i, \;\; f(z) = c_i e^{\alpha z} \tag{9}$

on $\Omega_i$.  If $z_i \in \Omega_i$, then by (7) we have

$f(z) = f(z_i)e^{\alpha(z - z_i)}, \tag{10}$

$z \in \Omega_i$.  Thus (7) provides a method for "automatically" explicitly specifying $f(z)$ on each component of $\Omega$.

Of course, when we unqualifiedly say, with our OP Reyo, "$f$ is holomorphic . . . for every $z \ne 0$" we generally understand $f(z)$ to be holomorphic on all of $\Bbb C \setminus \{ 0 \}$, which *is* connected. And indeed the general form of $f(z)$ given in (4) shows it may be extended to an entire function; we can take $z_0 = 0$ so that $f(z) = f(z_0) e^{\alpha z}$ and be done with it.  ***End of Note.***

Answer (score 2):

Multiply both sides by $e^{-\alpha z}$ and, with a little magic, you can make it happen.  I won't spoil things by saying any more.

Comment: Instead, Robert will spoil things.