# First-order differential equation

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

What class of functions $f(x)$ satisfies $f'(x)+f(x)=k$?

Comment: is your k constant?

Comment: how about multiply $e^x$ on both side, and try to diff $e^x f(x)$.

Comment: An elementary solution to a broader class of differential equations can be found [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/753801/55235).

Answer (score 2):

$(e^x f)' = e^x (f + f') = e^x k$.

$e^x f = \int^x_0 e^s k(s) + C$

$f = e^{-x} \int_0^x e^s k(s) ds + Ce^{-x}$

Answer (score 2):

I suppose that $ k$ is a real number. If yes, then you multiply both sides by $e^x$ and use that:

> If $f'(x) =g'(x), \quad \forall x \in I$, where $I \subset \mathbb R $
>   is an interval, then
>
> $$ f(x) = g(x) + c , \quad x \in I$$
>
> where $c \in \mathbb R $ is a constant.

Namely, in your case we have:

$ f'(x)+ f(x)= k \Longleftrightarrow e^x f'(x) + e^x f(x) = ke^x \Longleftrightarrow \left(e^x f(x) \right)' = (ke^x)' $

Thus, $e^x f(x) = k e^x + c, \quad x \in \mathbb R$, and $c$ is a real constant. Hence, you obtain:

$$ f(x) = ce^{-x} + k \quad x \in \mathbb R $$