# Solving differential equation with inhomogeneous part $\sin x \cos x$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

How do you solve the following inhomogeneous  differential equation:

$$ y' + y\cos x = \sin x \cos x  ?$$

I determined the homogeneous solution ($y_h=Ce^{-\sin x})$, but how do I find the particular solution? I tried using the ansatz $y_p = (P \sin x + Q\cos x)(S\sin x + Z\cos x)$, but this approach failed (I didn't succeed at least). What is the most bright approach? Thanks for any help!

Comment: The ODE is linear in $y$. Have you attempted to find an integrating factor?

Comment: [This](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/753797/solving-a-differential-equation/753801#753801) should work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$${ y }^{ \prime  }+y\cos { x } =\sin { x } \cos { x } $$
$$\Downarrow $$
$${ y }\prime +y\cos { x } =0$$
$$\Downarrow $$
$$\frac { dy }{ dx } =-y\cos { x } $$
$$\Downarrow $$
$$\int { \frac { dy }{ y }  } =-\int { \cos { x } dx } $$
$$\Downarrow $$
$$ lny+{ C }_{ 1 }=-\sin { x } +C_{ 2 }$$
$$\Downarrow $$
$$ y={ Ce }^{ -\sin { x }  }$$
$$\Downarrow $$
$$ y=C\left( x \right) { e }^{ -\sin { x }  }$$
$$\Downarrow$$
$$ { y }\prime =C\prime \left( x \right) { e }^{ -\sin { x }  }-C\left( x \right) \cos { x } { e }^{ -\sin { x }  }$$
$$\Downarrow$$
$$C\prime \left( x \right) { e }^{ -\sin { x }  }-C\left( x \right) \cos { x } { e }^{ -\sin { x }  }+C\left( x \right) \cos { x } { e }^{ -\sin { x }  }=\sin { x } \cos { x } $$
$$\Downarrow$$
$$C\prime \left( x \right) { e }^{ -\sin { x }  }=\sin { x } \cos { x } $$
$$\Downarrow$$
$$C\prime \left( x \right) ={ e }^{ \sin { x }  }\sin { x } \cos { x } $$
$$\Downarrow$$

$$C\left( x \right) =\int { { e }^{ \sin { x }  }\sin { x } \cos { x } dx } =\int { \sin { x } d } { e }^{ \sin { x }  }={ e }^{ \sin { x }  }\sin { x } -\int { { e }^{ \sin { x }  }\cos { xdx }  } ={ e }^{ \sin { x }  }\sin { x } -\int { d{ e }^{ \sin { x }  } } ={ e }^{ \sin { x }  }\left( \sin { x } -1 \right) +C$$
finally $$ y={ e }^{ -\sin { x }  }\left[ { e }^{ \sin { x }  }\left( \sin { x } -1 \right) +C \right] =\sin { x } -1+{ Ce }^{ -\sin { x }  }$$

Answer (score 4):

Use the integrating factor 
$$\mu(x) = \exp\left\{\int \cos(x)\ dx\right\} = e^{\sin(x)}.$$

Answer (score 1):

make the ansatz $y_p=A\sin(x)+B\cos(x)+C_1$ where $A,B,C_1$ are real numbers

Answer (score 0):

You could use $y_p=A\sin x+B$

this gives the equation $A\cos x+(A\sin x+B)\cos x=\sin x\cos x$.