# First-Order Linear Differential Equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have the following exepression in my book:

$$\frac{dx}{dt}+a_1(t)x=g(t), \ \ \ \ x(t_0)=x_0$$

Then it says, multiply both sides of the differential equation by the integrating factor $I(t)$.

$$I(t) \frac{dx(t)}{dt}+a_1(t)I(t)x(t)=I(t)g(t)$$

So far so good. Hereafter it says, the left-hand side is an exact derivative.

$$\frac{d[x(t)I(t)]}{dt}=I(t)g(t)$$

And my question is, how does the book come to the last? Can anyone give a HINT.

Comment: Do they tell you what the integrating factor is? Because if they do, you really just need to differentiate the LHS of the last equality. **Edit:** [This](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/753797/solving-a-differential-equation/753801#753801) should make it clear. Beware that the link isn't a hint at all, but I don't see what good a hint would be here, nor if a good hint exists in this case.

Answer (score 3):

I suppose that the integrating factor $I$ is defined by 
$$ I(t) = \exp\left(\int_{t_0}^t a_1(s)\, ds\right) $$
and hence has the property 
$$ I'(t) = \exp\left(\int_{t_0}^t a_1(s)\,ds\right)a_1(t) = I(t)a_1(t) $$
so 
$$ \frac{d}{dt}\bigl(x(t)I(t)\bigr) = \frac{d}{dt}x(t)\cdot I(t) + x(t) \cdot \frac{d}{dt} I(t) = \frac{d}{dt}x(t)\cdot I(t) + x(t)a_1(t)I(t) $$
which is the left hand side.

Comment: I am asuming you use the chain rule ($f'(g(x)) \cdot g'(x)$) but how do you take the derivative of the inner part?

Comment: By the fundamental theorem of calculus, we have $\frac{d}{dt}\int_{t_0}^t a(s)\,ds = a(t)$.

Comment: Yes of course it is. Sorry...